# How can I retrieve the session ID from within a JAX-RS webservice?

Tags: web-services, session, request, jax-rs

I cannot figure out how to retrieve the session ID from a given JAX-RS webservice request. I assume it is available, but I do not know how to retrieve it.

I am NOT using CXF. I would be grateful for any assistance.

Answer (score 26):

You can use the [`@Context` annotation](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs-javax.jax-rs/2.0.1/javax/ws/rs/core/Context.html) to get the current instance of the `HttpServletRequest`.

```
@Path("/session-id.txt")
public class SessionIdResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getSessionId(@Context HttpServletRequest request) {
        return request.getSession(true).getId();
    }
}
```